# Ionic Push Notification: Not receiving in IOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, ionic-framework, push-notification

**THE SITUATION:**

I use [Ionic Push Notifications](http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/) in my app.

With android everything works fine. But with IOS I don't receive any notification.

The code should be fine. The registration of the token it works properly also inside IOS devices. I can see the token in the database.

Also the cURL request code should be fine since it is working for android.

I will paste below all the info that may be useful:

**THE CODE:**

**Initialization:**

```
$ionicCloudProvider.init({

    "core": 
    {
        "app_id": "MY_APP_ID"
    },
    "push": 
    {
        "sender_id": "MY_SENDER_ID",
        "pluginConfig": {
            "ios": {
                "badge": true,
                "sound": true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**io-config.json:**

```
{"app_id":"MY_APP_ID","api_key":"MY_API_KEY","dev_push":false,"gcm_key":"MY_GCM_KEY"}
```

**THE CERTIFICATES:**

In ionic.io I have setup the certificate - production mode - and activate all the credentials:
[image: ionic.io certificate]

Inside the Apple Developer Console, the Push Notifications service is properly enabled (for production)

[image]

**THE TESTS:**

The app is already published in the App store.

Anyway i made tests both locally through XCODE (with the devices connected to it) and directly downloading the app from the app store.

I never received any notifications.

Making a test using POSTMAN this is the outcome:

```
{
  "data": {
    "status": "open",
    "uuid": "b55a9024-d0d9-480e-a813-02053bcf2f2a",
    "created": "2016-09-19T14:05:01.097422+00:00",
    "state": "enqueued",
    "app_id": "MY_APP_ID",
    "config": {
      "tokens": [
        "THE_RECEIVER_TOKEN"
      ],
      "notification": {
        "message": "Push test"
      },
      "profile": "MY_IONIC_IO_PROFILE"
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    "status": 201,
    "request_id": "dbb57cba-3817-42ee-baaf-7175b5f6c755",
    "version": "2.0.0-beta.0"
  }
}
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why I am not receiving any notification on IOS?

Am i missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure notifications are enabled in your iOS settings app
- Try using content_available = true in push payload
- Try using priority = "high" in push payload
- Make sure you're not sending using development certificates on a production app version or viceversa
- Make sure your token is valid and refreshed

[Docs about priority  and content_available attributes](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message)

From docs:

> On iOS, set content_available when the app server needs to send a Send-to-Sync message. An inactive client app will execute your logic in the background, while an app in the foreground will pass the message to didReceiveRemoteNotification:.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please give me a link of documentation about content_available and priority? I am using this documentation: https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/ and didn't find how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I have found the priority and content_available in the device option of the ionic.io send push notification test. I received the nofitication for android but not for IOS. I will research more on that anyway and on your other points.

Comment: It was a temporary bug in Ionic Cloud: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cloud/issues/50  Today everything works as it should. I will not delete the question because of your effort to answer. And maybe your answer can help somebody with a similar problem in the future. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Great! So there wasn't a right answer to your question but this could help

Comment: Yes exactly! It also helped me to learn about content_available and priority.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have latest version of Ionic i,e v2 and above.
2. In path src/app/app.components.ts
3. After `platform.ready().then(() => {` add the below code

   ```
   var push = Push.init({
    android: {
    senderID: "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    ios: {
     alert: "true",
     badge: true,
     sound: 'false'
    },
    windows: {}
   });

   push.on('registration', (data) => {
    console.log(data.registrationId);
    alert(data.registrationId.toString());
   });

   push.on('notification', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
   });
   ```
4. After build (ionic build ios) open the ionic project in Xcode and in general and team section choose an account which has paid apple developer account.
5. Then in capabilities enable push notification.
6. If all the other constraints like certificate and .p12 files are done as per apple guild lines then push will surely work.
7. For more info visit this link : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/push/